# Having desktop icons with Thunar on Arch Linux with Openbox

Tags: arch-linux, desktop, openbox

I'm using Arch Linux with Openbox as my window manager. And Thunar as my preferred file manager. I'm using `zsh` in case that's relevant in any way.

How would I go about having desktop icons? I find it very useful to have my desktop with symlinks to all my frequently used folders and apps.

I tried searching Google but haven't been able to find anything about accomplishing this with *only* Thunar. Or some script that accomplishes just that.

Comment: Openbox is a WM, not a DE; there is no "desktop" as such. Use tint2 or another launcher...

Comment: @jasonwryan I am aware it's a WM and not a DE. I'm asking how I could get desktop icons on my "desktop", grabbing those icons from the `~/Dekstop` folder.  If it's simply not possible using Openbox as the WM and Thunar as the file manager. I've no problem, just thought it would be nice...

Comment: Thunar is irrelevant for this, and open-/fluxbox are around for people who don't want the clutter of desktop icons; so asking how to introduce them to these is kind of weird.  Use  XFCE instead ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some file managers that also manage the desktop icons, but Thunar is not one of them.

The Xfce desktop uses [Xfdesktop](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xfdesktop/) to display the desktop icons, it depends on Thunar.

Alternatively you can use [iDesk](http://idesk.sourceforge.net/html/about.html), which has no dependencies to any of the mayor desktop environments, but needs to be configured by hand.

Some of the file managers which can display desktop icons are

- [Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Nautilus?action=show&redirect=Nautilus)
- [PCManFM](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM)
- [Spacefm](http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/)

All of them should work with Openbox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly I don't use Openbox or Arch Linux anymore (I'm now stuck on a Mac). Whenever I switch to Linux again though I'll keep this in mind, thanks! :)